# Ansible - rerun playbook on failed hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a playbook with a few tasks and I run it on all my inventory hosts.

I wish to rerun this playbook on failed hosts only (fail = the last task should be the trigger for success \ fail).

What would be a good ansible practice to accomplish it ?

I thought of dynamically creating a new inventory group named failed_hosts and somehow call the same playbook with that group only.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Q: ***"Rerun playbook on failed hosts."***

A: This is exactly the purpose of the configuration option [RETRY_FILES_ENABLED](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#retry-files-enabled). Quoting:

> *"
> This controls whether a failed Ansible playbook should create a .retry file."*

For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host01 test=true
host02 test=true
host99 test=false
```

the playbook below will fail on *host99*

```yaml
shell> cat pb3.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: test|bool
```

gives

```yaml
shell> pwd 
/scratch/tmp8/test-857
```

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED=true ansible-playbook pb3.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
ok: [host02] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
fatal: [host99]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: test|bool
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed
    to retry, use: --limit @/scratch/tmp8/test-857/pb3.retry

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host01: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host02: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host99: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The output says you can `use: --limit @/scratch/tmp8/test-857/pb3.retry`. See [ansible-playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html). The option `--limit` says:

> *"further limit selected hosts to an additional pattern"*

You can see that the 'retry file' *pb3.retry* was created and that the file includes the failed host

```
shell> cat /scratch/tmp8/test-857/pb3.retry
host99
```

Rerun the playbook on the failed host(s) only. For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb3.yml -e test=true --limit @/export/scratch/tmp8/test-857/pb3.retry

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [host99] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host99: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```